# Can i remove the space between Detail and Report footer sections in crystal report?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am very much worried with extra space which occurs in between my detail and report section, how can i vanish it,

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can drag separator (between `detail` sections and `footer` section) to remove space.

Answer (score 1):

If it's from Grouping (group header, group footer), you can suppress the report band.

If the extra space is IN the Details section, you can do like Thomas said, or right-click in the Details section at the left of the palette and select Fit Section from the drop-down.  You can also click (and hold) on the left margin, and drag to the right, and Crystal will ADD a section divider, which you can adjust inside your current Details band to split it.  This is useful if you have lots of fields, possible spaced out to accommodate large field contents, and you want to trim the size down.  Placing a section divider between fields will separate them, and you can re-size the fields to single line height, and then change their properties to "Can Grow".  That can reduce large details sections greatly.